# Incorrect syntax near <random changing character>

Tags: c#, sql, dbcontext

I'm super puzzled by this issue. I've looked up previous posts of 'incorrect syntax' but they had clear examples. I've got some C# code writing DbContext query code to my DB. I've got changing errors pointing at different characters in the same query code:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO AspNetUsers (Id, Email, 
EmailConfirmed, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp, UserName, Location, First_Name, 
Last_Name, Bio, Online_Collaboration, Instrument, Genre, PhoneNumberConfirmed, 
TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEnabled, AccessFailedCount) " +

"VALUES ('" + muser.Id + "', '" + muser.EmailAddress + "', 1, '" + 
muser.SecurityStamp + "', '" + muser.Username + "', '" + muser.Location + "', 
'" + muser.FirstName + "', '" + muser.LastName + "', '" + muser.Bio + "', 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)");
```

The errors range. These are some samples below but that 'syntax near x' changes between mainly these letters:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 't'.'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'll'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 's'.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'm'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common 
table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context 
clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.'

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'll'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common 
table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context 
clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '', 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0)'.'
```

What I've noticed so far:

- Characters mainly s, t, m and also ll. The 'll'  means it can't just be a single character issue. The characters are used frequently throughout the code so it's impossible to pinpoint although I'd imagine they're the symptom, not the cause.
- The 'Incorrect syntax near x' is the only consistent error. I believe the others are just follow-ons. Of the dozens of times I've ran it, it's more the minimal message.
- And finally the most frustrating part - it WORKS (very) infrequently so the syntax should be fine as far as I can see. Maybe it's shitting itself at the processioning end and some timings overlapping? There's a bit of string breaking for variables but I would imagine that's pretty standard load.

Comment: You need to use a parameterized insert, currently if you have a `'` in a value things will break horribly and expose you to SQL Injection.

Comment: First thing to do: use **parameterizd queries** instead of inserting _user input_ directly into your query string. your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://www.bobby-tables.com)!

Comment: Your input includes a ', and you are wide open to SQL injection. If someone enters `', 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); DROP TABLE AspNetUsers; -- ` into their bio field, your user table will be gone.

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd reference](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as a duplicate of this because parameterizing your query will fix your problem, and solve your huge SQL injection problem.

Comment: Parameterizing is definitely the way to go but hadn't you considered one of the very basics of debugging - rather than just staring at the code - print out the actual command string generated - look for the occurrences of things like 'll' or 'with' which do not appear in your code - it may become obvious exactly what the issue is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never create SQL queries/commands by concatenating strings. Not only does this make you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), it can also cause problems with string escaping as you experienced first hand.

The correct way to build commands is to use [`SqlParameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var commandText = @"
INSERT INTO AspNetUsers 
    (Id, Email, EmailConfirmed, PasswordHash, SecurityStamp, UserName, 
     Location, First_Name, Last_Name, Bio, Online_Collaboration, Instrument,
     Genre, PhoneNumberConfirmed, TwoFactorEnabled, LockoutEnabled,
     AccessFailedCount)
VALUES
   (@id, @email, 1, @securityStamp, -- and so on for other values
   )
";

var idParameter = new SqlParameter("id", muser.Id); 
var emailParameter = new SqlParameter("email", muser.EmailAddress); 
var securityStampParameter = new SqlParameter("securityStamp", muser.SecurityStamp); 

var parameters = new [] { idParameter, emailParameter, securityStampParameter };

db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(commandText, parameters);
```

Comment: Upvote earned by the end of the 1st paragraph. 
@thatsHeavyDoc, ignore this advice at your peril.

Comment: Excellent, I see what needs to be done. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Always glad to help :)